# Design requirements for AppExchange apps

Tags: appexchange, lightning-design-system, salesforce-classic, design

Are there any design requirements/restrictions for an AppExchange app? We would like to create a popup, which will work a bit like a chat screen that some web shops use, but smaller. It would be completely hidden unless there is a message to display. Is that allowed in classic/Lightning? I couldn't find any documentation on it.
[image: Example of pop up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as far as passing a security review, the [Security Review FAQ](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Security_Review_FAQ) places limits on what you can do with your app. Perhaps the most relevant part for you is the following section:

> **Q: I failed my security review because of “JS in Salesforce DOM". What does that mean and how can I get around it?**
>
> A: Javascript that is part of a partner offering may not execute
>   within the context of the Salesforce application
>   (instance.salesforce.com). This includes using custom Javascript in
>   standard and custom Objects. Instead, embed a Visualforce component in
>   the object’s page and have the VF page execute the necessary logic.
>   For more information see
>   https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Requirements_Checklist

As long as you can build something that does not violate the security rules, you're free to do as you will. Without knowing more details, it's hard to tell you exactly which way you'd want to go, but I suspect you'll want to make something that can integrate with the Chatter API so that Salesforce users can get notifications on the device of their choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sfdcfox! Good to know that there are no design requirements, only security requirements. I hadn't actually considered using the Chatter API to do this. I'll have to think about the possibilities that that offers. For now I have some more documentation to study in depth ;).